# How to install GNU flex or lex on Raspbian Raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, lex, raspbian

I need to install [EyedDB](http://www.eyedb.org/) for studies and I'd like to run it on my Raspbian Raspberry.
I downloaded and unzipped at `/usr/programs/EyeDB` where I ran first with Pi user as requested and later as root:

```
./configure
```

Then a bunch of lines is coming out and ended with

```
 error: you must have Gnu flex or lex installed to compile EyeDB
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, just get it like you would get anything else:

```
# apt-get install flex
```

You'll also need

```
# apt-get install bison
# apt-get install libreadline6-dev # for a non-maddening command line
```

...after which `configure --disable-doc` and `make` will sing their merry little songs and be happy (The `--disable-doc` is needed as `javadoc` chokes on  `Database.java`)

`flex` and `bison` are the GNU versions of the venerable Unix tools `lex` (scanner generator) and `yacc` (parser generator), used in countless  compilers and interpreters. They are never needed at runtime, so there is no need for separate `{bison,flex}` and `{bison,flex}-dev` packages.